# fixing improperly escaped string in javascript

Tags: php, android, ios, json, mootools

I'm connecting to a PHP webservice that returns URLs of images in JSON (using the PHP `json_encode` function).

I'm working within a mootools 1.2.5 system, which also needs to work on mobile phones.

The format of the image node returned in the data is like this:

```
"thumb": "<img src=\"http://photos.imgserv.com/201107222000000.jpg\"  />"
```

For some reason iphone and android see a NULL value when I pass the response.JSON to them. I can pass the response.text object to them with no problem, but then the JSON.decode fails since the double quotes are not escaped properly. If I manually add double back slashes on the image tags like this:

```
"thumb": "<img src=\\"http://photos.imgserv.com/201107222000000.jpg\\"  />"
```

it all works as designed. However, I'm having a hell of a time getting the right regexp to replace the `\"` in the original response.text with `\\"`.

Is there a "right" way to handle the response.JSON to mobile phones, and alternately how can I properly write the string.replace() regex to handle these escape chars?

Thanks!

EDIT TO ADD:

Here's two jsfiddles with the single and double backslash to show the issue:

Single backslash (doesn't decode/parse properly) -- http://jsfiddle.net/Qde6F/
Double backslash (does decode/parse properly) -- http://jsfiddle.net/Qde6F/1/

Comment: Can you amend the application to _know_ that the `<img src=` is in every response and simply pass back the URL?

Comment: unfortunately not easily. It could be done, but I'm hoping I can do this with some front end js rather than core modifications to the service.

Comment: Can you use a single quote for the `src` attribute instead of double?

Comment: Your snippet is valid JSON. There's something wrong with the parsing or elsewhere in the data.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary-- I agree but when it's handled as a string (response.text) it doesn't parse properly: http://jsfiddle.net/Qde6F/
With the double backslashes, it does parse properly: http://jsfiddle.net/Qde6F/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try something like this...

```
var src = "\"thumb\": \"<img src=\\\"http://photos.imgserv.com/201107222000000.jpg\\\"  />\"";
alert(src);
var dest = src.replace("\\\"","\\\\\"");
alert(dest);
```

ie, the replace expression is `replace("\\\"","\\\\\"")`, which replace `\"` with `\\"`

Ok, this worked for me in the jsfiddler

```
var text = '[{"thumb": "<img src=\"http://photos.imgserv.com/201107222000000.jpg\"  />" }]';

console.dir(text);
var dest = text.replace(/(src=)(\")([^"]+)(\")/g,"$1\\\"$3\\\"");
console.dir(dest);

console.dir(JSON.decode(dest));​
```

Basically the regex rewrites the `src="url"` to be `src=\"url\"`.

Comment: @stuckless-- thanks! that's does seem to work. Is it possible to modify the regex so it works on all instances of the `\"` (for example, what if there was an `alt` tag or some other attribute set?)

Comment: you can probably just replace `src=` to `=` in the regex.  I was trying to limit it to just src attributes.

Comment: thanks! that works properly. Anyone else looking for an answer, here's the final fiddle that works properly: http://jsfiddle.net/Qde6F/3/